# Error el intentar pasar parámetros en @include de laravel (5.3)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, laravel

Paso parámetros de la siguiente manera y me funciona:

```html
<?php 
    $datos = array('ruta' => '30',);
?>
@include('componentes.boton_listado_crear', $datos)
```

En el archivo que recibo la informacion lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```html
<button type="button" id="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
    <span class="hidden-xs"> Agregar</span>
</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ruta = '{{ $datos['ruta'] }}';
    var funcion = 'crear';
    var id_perfiles = '{{ Auth::user()->id_perfiles }}';

    $.get("tablero/getValidCRUD/"+ruta+"/"+funcion+"/"+id_perfiles+"/",function(resp){
         $("#Crear").attr("disabled", !resp.results);
    });
</script>
```

De esa manera me funciona bien la información y lo que deseo mostrar en la vista.

Ahora voy con mi problema:

Intento pasar parámetros a una función, en el cual el `@include` sera retornado como un `string`. A continuación me explico con lo que llevo hasta ahora:

Llamo la función:

```
ButtonEditar('30')
```

Acá la función que estoy llamando:

```html
function ButtonEditar(valor){
    <?php 
        $datos = array('ruta' => valor,);
    ?>
    return '@include('componentes.boton_listado_editar', $datos)';
}
```

Esto me genera el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización 1:**

Gracias al usuario `@MáximaAlekz` me aclaro un error bobo que estaba cometiendo:

```html
function ButtonEditar(valor){
    $datos = {ruta: $valor};
    return '@include('componentes.boton_listado_editar', $datos)'; 
}
```

[image: 2]

El contenido del archivo al cual llamo con el include, es el siguiente:

```html
<button type="button" class="editar edit-modal btn btn-warning ">
    <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
    <span class="hidden-xs"> Editar</span>
</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ruta = '{{ $datos['ruta'] }}';
    var funcion = 'crear';
    var id_perfiles = '{{ Auth::user()->id_perfiles }}';
</script>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56307/discussion-on-question-by-pablo-contreras-error-el-intentar-pasar-parametros-en).

Comment: ¿Ya esta solucionado? ¿Cual es el error?

Comment: @Franklin'jGil'z ya lo solucione de otra manera.. pero como tiene recompensa abierta no la puedo eliminar. Si nadie da una solución simplemente la eliminare después que pase la recompensa.

Comment: añade la respuesta tu mismo entonces.

Comment: @Franklin'jGil'z no lo solucione pasando parametros por `include`, sino de otra manera, no como la queria pero me da resultado, si alguien responde la solucion del error de la pregunta que hice, pues bien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En general lo que intentas hacer no es una muy buena práctica o por lo menos yo no la recomendaría, hay varias razones:

- Utilizar Blade (php) para retornar un string en JavaScript normalmente tendrá problemas con los "escapes".
- Lo que hace el código implicado es como un doble return, uno en php y luego otro return en JavaScript, en el fondo es como si intentaras pasar de PHP a HTML usando a JavaScript como un puente. Simplemente no.
- El código es poco reutilizable y las dependencias son muy altas.
- El código es complicado de leer y entender, tal vez por el motivo anterior.
- Blade no fue diseñado para eso, no es un API o similar.

Como siempre hay muchas opciones para resolver esto, pero voy a ilustrar las dos más sencillas y prácticas:

1. Tal vez la mejor práctica sería hacer una solicitud AJAX, y que esta entregue el string deseado, con los valores y la vista adecuada, de hecho puede ser un `$.get()` similar al que utilizas en la parte inicial que muestras.

   Esto permitiría no solo aislar el código y evitar un poco la mezcla no deseada de backend / template engine / frontend, sino que haría más entendible, reutilizable y documentable el código, y cada parte implicada tendría una "única" función definida.
2. Siempre que quieras "pasar" datos de PHP a JS, utiliza [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php), te va a ahorrar la gran mayoría de inconvenientes que puedas tener.

   Esta es la opción más simple, funciona y no tiene nada de malo usarla en la mayoría de los casos, es más una salida de emergencia en este problema puntual.

Comment: Lo resolví como dices, con `AJAX` utilizando `$.get()`. No lo quise publicar como respuesta porque no es una solución a la pregunta que hice o al menos así lo veo yo.

Comment: La respuesta al problema puntual es la opción 2 que planteo, pero realmente no sería la mejor práctica, es una mejor opción la otra solución y sí responde perfectamente la pregunta, _refactoring_ siempre será más que bienvenido.

Comment: Ok gracias, en lo que tenga mas chance me siento a responder algo bien hecho.

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo es

```
function ButtonEditar(valor){
    $datos = {ruta: $valor};
    return '@include('componentes.boton_listado_editar', $datos)'; 
}
```

en `function ButtonEditar(valor)`, creo que es `function ButtonEditar($valor)`

eso es lo que pinta el error.

ademas tienes comillas simple en todo lo que retorna la función

deberia quedar

```
return '@include("componentes.boton_listado_editar", $datos)';
```

y otra cosa no creo que necesites retornar el include al menos que el archivo retorne algo... ¿por que retornarías algo que estas incluyendo? si lo ves?